# I am trying to do an API call on openweather with string formatation in a jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, api, jupyter-notebook, string-formatting

```
import requests

api_key = "..."

city = input ("Hello, please insert city here!")
# Variable "url" which has the same structure as the API call, as formatted string
url = f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={city}&appid={api_key}&units=metric'

#sending the request at openweather...

data = requests.get().json(url)


temperature = data['main']['temp']
temperature_min = data['main']['temp_min']
temperature_max = data['main']['temp_max']

print(f'In the city of{city}the temperature  is{temperature}. The minimum temperature is{temperature_min}, the maximum is{'temp_max'})`
```

The Problem seems to be in the print statement,
I have tried everything else,  and that works. When I leave the print statement out, it works. There seems to be some problem with the string formatting or it is because of the jupyter notebook

Comment: `{'temp_max'}` should be `{temperature_max}` ? You may also want to add the missing whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

I got it, there was a inverted comma missing at the end of the print statement.
Sorry